# Webassembly how to get pointer or reference of f64

Tags: assemblyscript

Is there any method in assemblyscript which get the pointer of type f64?

It works:

```
let c: ClassA;
changetype<usize>(c)
```

It don't work

```
let f:f64
changetype<usize>(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive number types aren't heap allocated.  The are on the stack of the current function as a local variable.  If you want to allocate it you can use `__alloc`, e.g.

```
let f_ptr = __alloc(sizeof<f64>());
store<f64>(f_ptr, f);
```

If you are trying to pass the `f64` to javascript you don't have to use indirection since it is one of the possible types in import/exports, along with integers.

Comment: thanks, I have checked the handbook, it should be `heap.alloc(sizeof<f64>())`

Comment: Both should work.

https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/blob/4e8361733cd7cd974f7e6025d874e90818c584b9/std/assembly/rt/stub.ts#L32